# Snapshot test API client against wildly mutating remote API

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, jestjs, snapshot

Suppose I'm writing an API client for some intricate API out there, that is not reliable and might suddenly mutate without bumping API version. And I would like to test my client with Jest. I would like to be able to test the capabilities of my client on snapshot of the response from API rather than live API. But I don't want the snapshot to become stale, would be great to update it every now and then. My question is - can I do it with the Jests snapshot functionality?

Never used it previously but from what I understand Jest Snapshot is kind of opposite of what I need? Like it will dump the first response from the API and then on every test do the match of the live API response with what has been stored. In this case I don't need that. So is what I'm looking for possible or I should go with some DIY solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot testing is used for comparing objects with their previous state. For your use case you can take a look at

[Polly.JS](https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/adapters/node-http?id=node-http-adapter)

> Polly.JS is a standalone, framework-agnostic JavaScript library that enables recording, replaying, and stubbing of HTTP interactions.